# Kepler's position with respect to Tycho Brahe's world system?

Tags: astronomy, 17th-century, kepler

When Kepler was an assistant of Tycho Brahe, did Kepler in public declare his support for Copernicus' system or Brahe's system (the earth at rest, but the planets orbiting the sun) or was he undecided? The latter is told in the novel by Max Brod: "Tycho Brahe's path to God". But that's a novel only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kepler never supported Brahe's system in print. 
In his first book (1596) he proposes
his own version of heliocentric system. Collaboration with Brahe is 1600-1612.
During this period he wrote Astronomia Nova (1609) based on heliocentric system.
And all his later books are based on heliocentric system as well.

Comment: So Max Brod writes a lot of his own phantasy.

Comment: @Heinrich: I have not read what Brod writes.